# How to disable the dynamic attribute field in gwt

Tags: java, gwt

```
if (dto.isReadOnly()) {
    if (item instanceof ValueListBoxFormItem) {
        ((ValueListBoxFormItem<IdNamePairDto>) item).setValue(null);
    } else if (item instanceof CheckBoxFormItem) {
        item.setValue(Boolean.valueOf(false));
    } else if (item instanceof IntegerFormItem){
        item.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (item instanceof TextFormItem){
        item.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        item.setValue(null);
    }
}
```

I am getting 5 field as the dynamic attribute. After displaying that, depends upon one drop down value, I need to disable to another field. It is actually an text field which is an `IntegerFormItem`. I tried disabling that by giving `false`. But its not working. The entire text box is disappearing instead of getting disabled.

Comment: Is that SmartGWT? Please tag appropriately.

Comment: I am using GWT 2.7.0  version.

Comment: There's no `*FormItem` in GWT proper. Which additional library are you using?